# Google Maps geocoding : "google is not defined"

Tags: php, maps, prestashop, geocoding, google-geocoder

I'm getting an issue when I try to load this code, and I can't figure why it doesn't work...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        $(".textarea-autosize").autosize();

        geocoder.geocode({
            address: '{$order->address_delivery["address1"]},{$order->address_delivery["postecode"]},{$order->address_delivery["city"]}'
            }, function(results, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
            {
                var delivery_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
                    zoom: 10,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    center: results[0].geometry.location
                });
                var delivery_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: delivery_map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                    url: 'http://maps.google.com?q={$order->address_delivery["address1"]},{$order->address_delivery["postcode"]},{$order->address_delivery["city"]}'
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(delivery_marker, 'click', function() {
                    window.open(delivery_marker.url);
                });
            }
        });
    });

    // Fix wrong maps center when map is hidden
    $('#tabAddresses').click(function(){
        x = delivery_map.getZoom();
        c = delivery_map.getCenter();
        google.maps.event.trigger(delivery_map, 'resize');
        delivery_map.setZoom(x);
        delivery_map.setCenter(c);

    });
</script>
```

The error occurrs on the `var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();`

Then I tried to load the following script : `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>`

and I get another error :

> 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null'

Does anyone has any idea of why it doesn't work ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google maps aren't loaded at the time when you're trying to call it. You should be using this:

HTML:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

JS:

```
function initMap() {
    // Google maps are now initialized.
}
```

You need to include the [async and defer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API) attributes into your script - this will make sure that the rest of the website keep loading instead of waiting for the script to load (which is handy, because it's quite big).
Secondly, you pass the "callback" parameter when calling the script. This is the name of the function that should be executed when the script is loaded. This way you can make sure you only initialize the map when it's actually loaded and present within your window.

Comment: Perhaps a little greater explanation into what you did? I know, but I don't think OP will get it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this script to your html file:

```
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

If you want to test the google geocoding api or check out some code, check out this link. [Google Geocoding Service API Source](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple)